# r scatter plot with error bars in both directions

Tags: r, plot, scatter

How can I create a scatter plot with error bars in two directions? Usually the error bars are in the vertical direction (i.e. the uncertainty in the y value). However my data has uncertainty in the x value as well

```
X      ErrX   Y     ErrY
1.0    0.1    3.0   0.2
1.5    0.3    4.2   0.1
etc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ggplot2`, this is easy.  You have complete control over the length of all four "sides" of the errorbars.  With `geom_errorbar()` you set the y-errors, and `geom_errobarh()` (the h is for horizontal) you set the x-errors.

```
#toy data
df <- data.frame(X = rnorm(4), errX = rnorm(4)*0.1, Y = rnorm(4), errY = rnorm(4)*0.2)

#load ggplot2
require(ggplot2)

#make graph
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + geom_point() + #main graph
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Y-errY, ymax = Y+errY)) + 
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = X-errX, xmax = X+errX))
```

You have separate control for the color of each bar, the linewidth, etc by setting parameters inside `geom_errorbar()`.  See the help and Google for details.  For example, you can control the width of the "caps" or eliminate them entirely with the `width` parameter.  Compare the graph above to this one for an example of removing them:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + geom_point() + 
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Y-errY, ymax = Y+errY), width = 0) + 
        geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = X-errX, xmax = X+errX), height = 0)
```

Comment: Made several edits to correct typos in my initial writeup.  In particular, `geom_errorbarh` controls the "cap length" with the `height` parameter, analogous to the `width` for `geom_errobar`.

Comment: any idea of how caps can be removed only on onw side of the errorbar?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative (using Curt F. 's "df"):

```
rangeX = range(c(df$X + df$errX, df$X - df$errX))
rangeY = range(c(df$Y + df$errY, df$Y - df$errY))

plot(df$X, df$Y, xlim = rangeX, ylim = rangeY)

segments(df$X, df$Y - df$errY, df$X, df$Y + df$errY)
segments(df$X - df$errX, df$Y, df$X + df$errX, df$Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using error.crosses from my psych package + the toy data from Curt:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(mean=df$X,sd=df$errX)
 df2 <- data.frame(mean=df$Y,sd=df$errY) 
 error.crosses(df1,df2,sd=TRUE)
```

See the help page for error.crosses for some more complicated examples.