# R scatterplot matrix with error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

Is there any R package/method/function that provides the functionality to plot a matrix of scatterplots as [here](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/images/spmatrix3.png) (`scatterplot.matrix` function of the `car` package, found [here](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/scatterplot.html)) AND to plot x and y errorbars as has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522831/r-scatter-plot-with-error-bars-in-both-directions).

An example:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(X = rnorm(10), errX = rnorm(10)*0.1, Y = rnorm(10), errY = rnorm(10)*0.2, Z = rnorm(10))
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Y-errY, ymax = Y+errY)) + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = X-errX, xmax = X+errX)) + theme_bw()
```

produces the following plot (X vs Y with errorbars): 
[image]

while

```
library(car)
spm(~X+Y+Z, data=df)
```

produces a scatterplot matrix such as this: [image]

Now my expected output would be such a matrix of scatterplots (any other package than `car` will be fine as well) where I can also display errorbars. (Note that not all of my variables have errors, e.g. `Z` does not). Also the fitting etc that is done here by the `spm` function is a nice gimmick but not necessary for my means.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example and some code to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Data**

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(X = rnorm(10), errX = rnorm(10)*0.1,
                 Y = rnorm(10), errY = rnorm(10)*0.2,
                 Z = rnorm(10))
```

**Code**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtools)
valCols <- c("X", "Y", "Z")
errCols <- setNames(c("errX", "errY", NA), valCols)
combn <- permutations(length(valCols), 2, valCols)

mdf <- do.call(rbind,
               apply(combn, 1, function(ind) {
                  df[["NA.Column"]] <- NA
                  errC <- errCols[ind]
                  errC[is.na(errC)] <- "NA.Column"
                  vals <- setNames(data.frame(df[, ind]), paste0("val", seq_along(ind)))
                  errs <- setNames(data.frame(df[, errC]), paste0("err", seq_along(errC)))
                  ret <- cbind(vals, errs)
                  ret$var1 <- factor(ind[1], levels = valCols)
                  ret$var2 <- factor(ind[2], levels = valCols)
                  ret
               }))

(p <- ggplot(mdf, aes(x = val1, y = val2, 
                      ymin = val2 - err2, ymax = val2 + err2,
                      xmin = val1 - err1, xmax = val1 + err1)) +
         geom_point() + 
         geom_errorbar() + geom_errorbarh() + 
         facet_grid(var1 ~ var2, drop = FALSE))
```

**Explanation**

First, you have to transform your data in a way, such that `ggplot2` likes it. That is, one column each for your x- and y-axis respectively plus one column each for the error bars.

What I used here, is function `permutations` from `library(gtools)`, which returns (in this case) all 2 element permutations. For each of these permutations, I select the corresponding column from the original data set and add the related error columns (if existing). If the column names follow a certain pattern for value and error bar columns, you can use `regex` to determine these automatically like in:

```
valCols <- names(df)[grepl("^[A-Z]$", names(df))]
```

Finally, I add the columns `var1`and `var2` describing which variables were selected:

```
head(mdf)
#          val1       val2        err1        err2 var1 var2
# 1 -0.56047565 -1.0678237  0.12240818  0.08529284    X    Y
# 2 -0.23017749 -0.2179749  0.03598138 -0.05901430    X    Y
# 3  1.55870831 -1.0260044  0.04007715  0.17902513    X    Y
# 4  0.07050839 -0.7288912  0.01106827  0.17562670    X    Y
# 5  0.12928774 -0.6250393 -0.05558411  0.16431622    X    Y
# 6  1.71506499 -1.6866933  0.17869131  0.13772805    X    Y
```

Having the data transformed this way makes it rather easy to generate the scatter plot matrix. With this approach it is also possible to modify the diagonal panel as shown in the follwing example:

```
p + geom_text(aes(ymin = NULL, ymax = NULL, xmin = NULL, xmax = NULL), 
              label = "X",
              data = data.frame(var1 = "X", var2 = "X", 
                                val1 = 0, val2 = 0))
```

**Plot**

[image: Scatterplot Matrix]
[image: Scatterplot Matrix With Diagonal Element]

Comment: This is a great answer and a very flexible solution! +1

Comment: I checked your code and I'm pretty sure that it should be `facet_grid(var2 ~ var1, drop = FALSE)` so that the distribution of variables in columns is the same along the x-axis and in rows along the y-axis, which is not the case right now. Please edit if you can confirm.

Comment: Well, the lhs (i.e. y) of `y ~ x` determines the rows and the rhs (i.e. x) the columns. If you switch them, you 'transpose' the matrix. But I am not sure whether I understood your comment properly, can you rephrase?

Comment: @thotal let's tale the last plot and the lower line of plots: I expect the y-axis to belong to the z variable in both plots and the x-axis to belong to the x variable in the plot in the left and to the y variable in the middle plot. But since both subplots derive from the same dataset I would expect to be able to draw a horizonzal line from each point in the left subplot to the same point (same z value) in the middle plot. This isn't the case here as you can see from e.g. the highest points in both subplots. Instead the lefternmost points in both plots coincide. Is this more helpful?